# C++: <sys/sysctl.h> fails to declare functions CTL_HW and HW_NCPU

Tags: c++, header-files

Aloha all!

I'm working with the following script (which I did not write). This is one of many files I've been working on modifying to initiate a build/make on Linux.

Everything I've found online suggests that *sys/sysctl.h* should properly declare these functions:

*CTL_HW* and *HW_NCPU*

However, running the following (called "machineInfo.cpp"):

```
#include "machineInfo.h"

#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <linux/sysctl.h>
#include <cstdio>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(a) (sizeof (a) / sizeof ((a)[0]))

int StMachineInfo::numProcs(void) {

    int numCPU = 0;
    int nprocs;
    size_t len = sizeof(nprocs); 
    static int mib[2] = { CTL_HW, HW_NCPU };

    /* get the number of CPUs from the system */
    sysctl(mib, 2, &numCPU, &len, NULL, 0);

    if( numCPU < 1 ) 
        {
        mib[1] = HW_NCPU;

        if (sysctl (mib, ARRAY_SIZE(mib), &nprocs, &len, NULL, 0) == 0 && len == sizeof (nprocs) && 0 < nprocs)
            numCPU = nprocs;

        if( numCPU < 1 )
            numCPU = 1;
        }
    return numCPU;

}
```

...results in the following error output:

```
g++  -c machineInfo.cpp
machineInfo.cpp: In function ‘int StMachineInfo::numProcs()’:
machineInfo.cpp:14:24: error: ‘CTL_HW’ was not declared in this scope
  static int mib[2] = { CTL_HW, HW_NCPU };
                        ^
machineInfo.cpp:14:32: error: ‘HW_NCPU’ was not declared in this scope
  static int mib[2] = { CTL_HW, HW_NCPU };
                                ^
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'machineinfo.o' failed
make: *** [machineinfo.o] Error 1
```

Is there something wrong with the code itself? Or do I need to #include another header? I've experimented with this and Googled for a couple of hours, to no avail.

Many thanks,

Sean

Comment: Please post here the output of the command `echo | g++ -dM -E - | grep linux`

Comment: Not responding to requests for clarification is a good way to earn a down vote.

Comment: I've [replicated the findings](https://gist.github.com/jaraco/5502059bb64531b115944d6eba388eef) using Docker and Ubuntu 18.04, including the requested output.

Comment: @JasonR.Coombs This was right before I ventured off for a field-expedition, and I had forgotten about this post completely. My bad. I wasn't able to solve this problem explicitly, but it turns out that the effort was wasted, since all I had to do to make/install the program of interest was call on the compiler (which was already installed on the computing cluster I was working from).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem here is that [sysctl does not have a glibc wrapper on Linux](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sysctl.2.html). By my best understanding, those constants are [only available on BSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sysctl(3)).

I'd be happy to be proven wrong, as I'm trying to understand if [this uname -p behavior](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/66e2daa689fefec9ed201a04696b9f52d049d89a/src/uname.c#L301-L343) could ever work on Linux.